# Woocommerce products from category loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

In Woocommerce, I Need some help with this custom product loop, in my code my result is : [how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPFey.png)

The loop doesn't stop and it is looping the same products for three or four times.

The code I am using is here :

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="default_products_page_container" class="wrap wpsc_container">
        <?php
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
            $cat = get_query_var( 'product_cat' );
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'product_cat' => $cat, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
        <div class="wpsc_default_product_list">
            <?php
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="default_product_display product_view_<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ); ?>group">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>"/>
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID ))
                    {            
                    ?>         
                    <div class="product-image-thumb"> 
                        <img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url( $loop->post->ID );?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    } else 
                    {?>
                    <div class="product-image-thumb">
                        <a>
                            <img src="<?php echo woocommerce_placeholder_img_src();?>"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please edit the code for better indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, although it will take all products in the loop (including those marked as "draft" when you are logged in). You can define only published by adding `'post_status' => 'publish'` to your argument variable.

And you should take a look at those anchor tags (specifically the close part)

Answer (score 3):

**I Hope this code gonna help you guys :)**

```
    <ul class="products">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'product_cat' => 'Shampoo',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'orderby' => 'rand'
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        global $product; ?>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- <h2>Shampoo</h2> -->
            <li class="product">

                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($loop->post->ID) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">

                    <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash($post, $product); ?>

                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID)) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog');
                    else echo '<img src="' . woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() . '" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>

                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                    <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>

                </a>

                <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart($loop->post, $product); ?>
            </li>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
<!--/.products-->
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a [**tax query**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) instead this way:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy'         => 'product_cat',
        'field'            => 'slug', // Or 'term_id' or 'name'
        'terms'            => get_query_var( 'product_cat' ), // A slug term
        // 'include_children' => false // or true (optional)
    )),
    'orderby' => 'rand'
) );
```

Tested and works on Woocommerce product category archive pages…

Comment: Same problem. I have only 6 products in my shop, but the code was printing 9 :D

Comment: I think the main problem is at posts per page

Comment: @AurimasGelžinis The `post_per_page` limit the number of displayed products… If you use the value `-1`, there is no limitation… I have tested your code and for me it works without duplicated products… So there is something else somewhere that is making this happen.

Comment: It can be because of my css? when i do it without, it work's great